# How to identify a struct member 'from char' in C?

Tags: c, struct

in C, I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t s2Cal1;
    uint16_t s2Cal2;
    uint16_t s2Cal3;
} global_data_t;

global_data_t my_toba;

my_toba.s2Cal1 = 10;
my_toba.s2Cal2 = 20;
my_toba.s2Cal3 = 30;
```

How can I update members in my struct 'identified by a char'? (I apologise for the unclear wording).

For example,

```
char * field_id = "s2Cal3";
// in other languages I could perhaps do
my_toba."field_id" = 200;
//resulting in 
//my_toba.s2Cal3 = 200;
```

Is something similar possible in C?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. C doesn't have reflection.

Comment: You can't. The variable names don't exist in compiled code. You'll need to somehow associate names with the fields in your code if you want to access them by name, but in this particular case, replacing those 3 values with an array and simply using array indices to address the correct one will work. You could use a `union` in your `struct` to keep the variable names in code if you need them.

Comment: I suspect that we have a duplicate. Anybody knows one?

Comment: This is a very common misconception among beginners: mixing up variable names and user I/O. Please note that variable/function/etc names in a program exist _solely for the benefit of the programmer_. Once the program is compiled, all names are removed from the final executable - it does not care what names you used and after linking they no longer exist. Neither should the user know or care about names in the _internals_ of the program they are using. So this kind of design is just confused - instead come up with user-friendly terms and don't mix those up with your variable names.

Comment: In your case change members to an array and access by index.